# Unable to update embedded item in a mongo document (no method update)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that looks like this, that I am able to update and query just fine:

```
// Subscriber Schema
var Subscriber = new Schema({
    'user': ObjectId,
    'level': { type: String, enum: [ 'sub', 'poster', 'blocked' ] }, //blocked means users has opted out of list
    'dateAdded': { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

// Group Schema
var Group = new Schema({
    'groupEmail': { type: String, lowercase: true, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'an email is required'], index: { unique: true } },
    'groupOwner': ObjectId,
    'groupName': String,
    'twitterFeed': String,
    'subscribers': [Subscriber],
    'createdAt': { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I'm trying to update a Subscriber within the Group document, and change its level, then save the change. I'm able to find the group just fine using:

```
Group.findOne({ _id: req.params.groupId }, function(err, g)
```

Once I have the group, I want to find a subscriber so I can update it. If I try:

```
g.subscribers.update({ 'user': req.params.userId }, { level: newStatus });
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Object { user: 4fc53a71163006ed0f000002,
  level: 'sub',
  _id: 4fd8fa225904a5451c000006,
  dateAdded: Wed, 13 Jun 2012 20:37:54 GMT },{ user: 4fda25ac00cd9bdc4f000004,
  level: 'sub',
  _id: 4fda270bbce9f8d058000005,
  dateAdded: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 18:01:47 GMT },{ user: 4fda2a634499dfd16e00000d,
  level: 'sub',
  _id: 4fda2a634499dfd16e00000e,
  dateAdded: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 18:16:03 GMT } has no method 'update'
```

I've tried various permutations of update, find, etc. but always get the "has no method" error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way I should be updating Subscriber.level?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

@eltoro is mostly correct, arrays do not have an `update` method, and the suggestion to use `Group.update` is a good one, but the update syntax is missing the `$` in `subscribers.$.level`.

```
Group.update(
    {_id: req.params.groupId, 'subscribers.user': req.params.userId}, 
    { 'subscribers.$.level': newStatus }, function(err, result) {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the error because you're calling update on the instance instead of the model.

Maybe try something like this:

```
Group.update(
    {_id: req.params.groupId, subscribers.user: req.params.userId}, 
    { subscribers.level: newStatus }, function(err, result) {}
);
```

Comment: No joy. Compile error on "unexpected '.' with subscribers.user and subscribers.level" when I try the above, and if I put both of those in quotes I get: `MongoError: can't append to array using string field name [level]`